# Sonar Analysis - Component version in Maven multi modules context

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I use **Sonar 3.5.1** in a context of a **Maven3 multi modules projects**. During the Sonar analysis, I have remarked that Module (component) version used into Sonar report is the version of the Parent project (POM). There is a way in order that Sonar use the version of the Module and not the version of the Parent project (POM) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the modules have a different version scheme than their parent, may be this means that they should be independent, don't you think? (what's the point of having coupled-lifecycle components if they don't follow the same versions?) And in turn, they should be built and analysed separately.